# How do I change the instance name in MS SQL 2005 without installing a new instance?

Tags: sql-server-2005, instance

I have an instance that really has nothing on it, it's merely been installed (it was intended for one project, but that never actually got done on this server, the project was done in duplicate on another server) so since I have the instance, I want to rename it.

Can this be done? How would I do so?

---

Further investigation (googling) says it's not really possible. Additional consultation with my coworkers says I might as well install a 2k8 instance and move on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible.

> You need to reinstall it. There is no
>   instance rename facility for the
>   Database Engine.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/d5d297b0-2995-46ba-9d3b-d1ec8825f479

Comment: Yeah, that's what I came down to, running the 2k8 installer atm. Thanks anyways. The real question is keep+answered, close or delete? I guess keep as answered for searchers in the future.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Definitely leave as answered.  When in doubt, you can always flag for moderator attention and let them make the call.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the instance name, but if I may suggest, you may be able to use `server aliases` instead. Eg: if your DB server was *stackexchange* and the instance name was *sql2005*, you would connect to the sql server by going to *stackexchange\sql2005*. An alias can be setup in the SQL configuration manger with a name of lets say *dbaxchange* and then pointed to *stackexchange\sql2005*. Now when you want to connect to your server, only provide the name of *dbaxchange* and it will be as though you are connecting to *stackexchange\2005*.

Comment: Yes, aliases are very useful. +1  Just be careful that you enable the protocol they it uses, and (if TCP/IP) that the right port number is selected.  Aliasing the default instance is fine, but if you're aliasing a non-default, you need to use a different port from 1433.